# Rooting and flashing the DX2

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, rom-flashing, rom, motorola-droid-x2

I have a DX2 I recently rooted (2.3.5) with some self root package. 
However, I didn't realize virtually all of the CM roms require 2.3.4. So now I need to SBF back to 2.3.4, re-root and flash. I'd like CM7, and maybe even try CM10. 
Is there a comprehensive site with all the necessary files in 1 location? I've searched all over forums and so many sites have dead links. I'm a bit of a noob, but have flashed the optimus elite once before..this motoblur crap is annoying..

Edit :
DX2 = droid x2
CM = cyanogenmod
SBF = system boot file
noob = beginner or novice

Comment: CM 4 DX2 w/ SBF? A AAAAA! (Alert the American Association Against Acronym Abuse) #D Following the tags you've used (`rom`, `root`, `rom-flashing`) you will find the necessary information: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575), [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575). If "DX2" stands for "Motorola Droid X2" (can you confirm?), that's still missing in the index -- but check the rooting methods, one of them might fit.

Comment: Thanks.. These acronyms should be familiar to all "android enthusiasts" aka this forum..but I agree with you, too many abrves..I will check the link out

Comment: So looks like I guessed right with all of them (hard to spell out SBF, I agree, and CM should be also pretty clear -- just the DX2 might need a little expansion, as others might not be that lucky with their guesses -- and simply skip your question). Also, the "Motorola" part I just guessed from the SBF and Motoblur -- remember that e.g. HTC has a "Droid" series as well (oops, OK, the tag should fix that :). It never hurts to be as precise as possible :) // BTW: I just added your question to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575).

Comment: Thanks again. The phone is so old now that I'm sure development for it has ceased.. but I just switched to page plus and it requires you to use a 3G phone, unless of course you flash a ROM to a 4G phone to make it pick up 3G only.. but I have no interest in dropping $300 plus for a new phone when the DX2 is really all I need (/end rant).

Comment: You're welcome -- and your reason is 100% understandable. Have you checked some of the rooting methods mentioned in above link? There are several of them which should work on Gingerbread.